# Create-react-app 137 vulnerabilities (123 moderate, 13 high, 1 critical)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm totally new to REACT and trying to follow a tutorial on YouTube. When I ran "npx create-react-app toDo" I get a bunch of vulnerability error. Following the instructs and ran "npm audit fix --force". This gave me more vulnerabilities then the initial vulnerability list.

I'm runing node.js v16.13.2 and npm v8.1.2. Someone please point me in the right direction please!

> 137 vulnerabilities (123 moderate, 13 high, 1 critical)
>
> To address issues that do not require attention, run:   npm audit fix
>
> To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
> npm audit fix --force
>
> Some issues need review, and may require choosing a different
> dependency.

Answer (score 2):

It's a lot of false positive or non important errors, I encourage you to read the following article: https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/
It has been written by Dan Abramov, co-author of Redux and Create React App.

Comment: The Create React App project has also pinned the following explanation to their GitHub Issues page: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174